# How to add HTML section in Perl POD using Pod::Weaver

Tags: perl, perl-pod

I use [Pod::Weaver](https://metacpan.org/module/Pod%3a%3aWeaver) with [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla). It does several good things for me. It adds POD section VERSION, AUTHOR, LICENSE automatically, and in my source code I can use simple POD syntax, I can write "=method new" and it will be converted to correct POD.

Now I wanted to add an image to the POD. To do it I need to add some HTML. So I'm writing in my [source code](https://github.com/bessarabov/StatusBoard-Graph/blob/757efd497a1d89d498db3c3fc1cd078a4a52422a/lib/StatusBoard/Graph.pm#L46):

```
=begin HTML

<p>
<a href="http://upload.bessarabov.ru/bessarabov/031VBX4pHw_ALPcxRTVjflnAWuc.png">
<img src="http://upload.bessarabov.ru/bessarabov/VdagpUXEQdMslOqUyOAzwa-DOaU.png" width="500" height="125" alt="Status board graph sample" />
</a>
</p>

=end HTML
```

Then I write `dzil release` and release the [module](https://metacpan.org/module/StatusBoard%3a%3aGraph) on CPAN. After uploading to CPAN I recognize that my HTML POD was changed by Pod::Weaver and now it looks like:

```
=for HTML <p>
<p>
<a href="http://upload.bessarabov.ru/bessarabov/031VBX4pHw_ALPcxRTVjflnAWuc.png">
<img src="http://upload.bessarabov.ru/bessarabov/VdagpUXEQdMslOqUyOAzwa-DOaU.png" width="500" height="125" alt="Status board graph sample" />
</a>
</p>
```

And this HTML part has been moved in the POD. I wanted it to be just after SYNOPSIS part, but not it is after the last method.

I still want to use Pod::Weaver, because it does a lot of good things, but I want HTML to be put in the exact place of the POD and not to be converted.

How can I do it?

Comment: I don't see `=end HTML` in the generated Pod?

Comment: Yep, my mistake. I've edited the post. And here is the link to the generated pod: https://metacpan.org/source/BESSARABV/StatusBoard-Graph-1.0.0/lib/StatusBoard/Graph.pm#L408

Comment: `=begin html`..`=end html` and `=for html` are basically synonymous, so nothing to worry about. However, the relocation of this paragraph might be a bug in `Pod::Weaver` and should probably be reported.

Comment: "Basically" is not quite the problem, `=for html`  requires all the html content occur on the same line before the `\n` at the end of line, while `=begin html` supports multiple `\n` in the content. Blithly translating one, to the other, while preserving `\n` causes invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

After much reading of `perldoc perlpod` and testing, the following things are apparent:

1. According to spec, `=begin html` segments **can** be translated safely to `=for html` segments.
2. However, this may only occur when the body of the segment contains segments that are grouped in paragraphs. So `foo\nbar` can be translated, but `foo\n\nbar` cannot.
3. The [module that is doing the transformation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod%3a%3aElemental%3a%3aTransformer%3a%3aPod5) from `=begin` to `=for`, when seeing a double `\n` in its body, refuses to emit `=for`, and instead, reverts to emitting `=begin`.

Given what number 3 Here is, If you want to force it to emit `=begin html`, simply spicing it up with a few extra `\n`'s will do the trick.

However, the problem remains, that for whatever reason, what appears to be valid POD format given, is not rendering as intended.

Either

- A. The Pod2HTML layer is not coded right to respond to `=for` ( in which case, a few extra `\n`'s to force an `=begin` may help.
- B. There's a security level thats preventing you from using complex HTML ( which may entail hyperlinks in images, which could be an XSS security threat )

If the problem is **B**, then you're not going to get around that by being tricky.

Though I assure you, displaying images **IS** doable, [I do it myself](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aApp%3a%3aCommand%3a%3adumpphases)